# select divs that are inside a div and with id that starts with mbItem?

Tags: jquery

I have probably made some error in this line of code:

`$('#mbContentText [name^="mbItem"]').css({color: "#006699", fontWeight: "normal"});`

The thing I'm trying to do is to select all divs with an id that contains "mbItem" that are inside a div with an id "mbContentText". Help is preciated!

EDIT:
I discovered that's the A tag that I want to affect only, and I wonder if can select only the A tags inside the div I'm selecting?

Comment: `id !== name` you are selecting elements which `name` starts with `mbItem`. If you change it to `id` it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your id name is `'mbItem'` and in your script you have written name inplace of id..so do the fallowing

```
$('#mbContentText [id^="mbItem"]').css({color: "#006699", fontWeight: "normal"});
```

to do same for A tags give class to those A, for example `anchor` and then do fallowing-(it will work if your A tags or inside `mbItem` div)

```
 $('#mbContentText [id^="mbItem"]').find('anchor').css({color: "#006699", fontWeight: "normal"});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following;

```
$('#mbContentText div[id*=mbItem]').css({color: "#006699", fontWeight: "normal"});
```

Comment: The other solutions change the attribute selector to the correct attribute (id), which is good. This is better than those, because it also changes the attribute selector to a contains (`*=`) rather than a starts with (`^=`).

Comment: @Spycho, thanks. I hadn't noticed that the other solutions where using '^=' and therefore wrong. The original question stated contains which requires "*=" as you say.

Answer (score 1):

change name to id?

```
$('#mbContentText [id^="mbItem"]').css({color: "#006699", fontWeight: "normal"});
                   ^^
```

Comment: Thanks! Discovered that I need to select just the A tags, is it possible to affect only the A tags that are inside the divs I'm selecting?